# Sub-exponential for Subset Sum on the total bit length of the input

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, runtime-analysis

Was crawling the internet, and found this in a paper (1)

*"[...], a variant of dynamic programming called
dynamic dynamic programming has been shown to have a worst-case sub-exponential time complexity of $2^{O(\sqrt x)}$ when the total bit length $x$ of the input set is used as the complexity parameter."*

As I understand this claim violates the Exponential Time Hypothesis, and there has been some answers in the forum clearly stating no such sub-exponential algorithm exists, would be interesting to know what the experts in the area think about the proposed algorithm in terms of worst case complexity.

Direct link to the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268397336_A_Simple_2_O_x_Algorithm_for_PARTITION_and_SUBSET_SUM) (2) explaining the dynamic dynamic approach.

(1) Thomas E. O’Neil -An Empirical Study of Algorithms for the Subset Sum Problem

(2) Thomas E. O’Neil, Scott Kerlin - A Simple $2^{O(\sqrt x)}$ Algorithm for PARTITION and SUBSET SUM

Comment: Sounds interesting.  Can you clarify what your question is?  Are you asking for a justification for the running time bound listed?  Something else?  Not sure what  you mean by "the reason".  Also, can you edit the question to give a full citation to the paper (title, authors, where published), so that the question  still makes sense even if the link stops working, and so that others with a similar question about the paper can find this page by searching on the paper title?  Thank you!

Comment: Let me do the changes

Comment: If there exists an $o(n^2)$ reduction from SAT to Subset-Sum [and papers are correct], ETH fails. But does such reduction exist?

Comment: Note: standard reduction from SAT is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't violate the exponential time hypothesis.  The [exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) says that k-SAT takes exponential time, i.e., $\Omega(2^{cn})$ for some constant $c>0$.  So if you found a $O(2^{\sqrt{n}})$ time algorithm for k-SAT, that would violate the exponential time hypothesis -- but a a $O(2^{\sqrt{n}})$ time algorithm for subset sum does not violate the hypothesis.

Comment: I was thinking this could be the case, thanks for confirming, the sub-exponential worst case question is still there, but this clear out the ETH issue.